# How to add a DKIM signature to classic ASP email sent using CDO

Tags: email, asp-classic, dkim, cdo.message

Using something like the below, is it possible to add a header for a DKIM signature? From what I've been reading, it doesn't look like it.. Why not?

```
Dim iMsg, iConf, Flds
Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

Set Flds = iConf.Fields

Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2

With Flds
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = cdoSendUsingPort 
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "server"
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'basic 
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "abc"
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "123"
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 10
.Update
End With

With iMsg
Set .Configuration = iConf
.To = recipient
.From = "foo@bar.com"
.Subject = "subject"
.HTMLBody = "body"
.Send
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the signature, you could add it to the Fields property of your `iMsg` object.  I've done something similar before to set the "Reply To" and "Return Receipts" addresses:

```
.Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:disposition-notification-to") = "test@example.com"
.Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:return-receipt-to") = "test@example.com"
```

You could do the same to add any custom header, in your case the DKIM signature.  Your `iMsg` object becomes:

```
With iMsg
  Set .Configuration = iConf
  .To = recipient
  .From = "foo@bar.com"
  .Subject = "subject"
  .HTMLBody = "body"
  .Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:DKIM-Signature") = "YOUR_SIGNATURE_HERE"
  .Send
End With
```

I hope that helps.